# Can't set constraints of UItableView's tableHeaderView height by autolayout in Storyboard

Tags: ios8, autolayout

I want the screen only shows one tableveiwCell with headerView.I added a UIView as header view on the top of UITableView with "Size classes" in storyboard(Just drag a UIView on the top of the UITableView), it can compatible with all devices screen size in this way.

So change header view's height by constraints is what i want to. but when i try to do that, i cant set constraints for the headerView(Xocde doesn't enable me select any constrains in storyboard, Image 2 below). As below.

Any ideas, thanks!

The project code is here: https://github.com/williamhqs/AutoLayoutTableViewHeaderView

[image: screenshot]

[image]

**EIDT:**
Seems it still can't be set in storyboard.

Then i will have to change table header view's frame by code then update constraints.

```
UIView *v = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
CGRect fr = v.frame;
fr.size.height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -100;
v.frame = fr;
[self.tableView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Comment: i don't understand adding header view?? is that a normal view and you name it as header view?

Comment: Will you please share your project.

Comment: @Jageen add header view is just drag UIView at the top of the UITableView as the tableViewHeaderView, sure, will share it now by gitHub

Comment: @Jageen here it is https://github.com/williamhqs/AutoLayoutTableViewHeaderView thanks!

Comment: Ok i will downlaod it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then i will have to change table header view's frame by code then update constraints.

```
UIView *v = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
CGRect fr = v.frame;
fr.size.height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -100;
v.frame = fr;
[self.tableView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that UIView doesn't have any **superview** So that it is not showing the constraints for view.