# UITableView header height will not change in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a `Storyboard` that is using a `UITableViewController`. I have added a `UIView` as the `UITableView` header and set the height to 200. But, for some reason, when I preview it, the header is huge! looks to be about 540 high (header is white):

[image]

Here are my settings:

[image]

It looks correct in the storyboard preview. What could be causing it to be so huge and prevent my height setting from working?

Comment: Did you tried to remove view, and put it and configure again?

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko - Yes.

Comment: strange... Can you share table header autolayout constraints? I trying reproduce issue, but for me everything works fine... Maybe you modify tableHeaderView somewhere inside the code?

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko - I have other `UITableViewController`'s in my storyboard with header views and they don't have the issue. Super strange. The header view itself has no constraints. It doesn't allow you to add constraints directly to the header view.

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko - Just created a new `UITableViewController` and have the same issue.

Comment: I ended up copying and pasting the `UIView` that I used as a tableView header else where and that fixed the issue. Sounds like an XCode bug!

Comment: I can't reproduce issue. Can you share your nib file or some test project? For me everything looks fine: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48223929/Untitled.tiff

Comment: Yeah, I can't share my nib file. I think there is some inconsistency within the storyboard file that is causing the UI to not update the XML code that makes up the nib.

Comment: Have you registered the  Nib file ViewDidLoad like

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apple figured it out. Here is what they said:

> Because the frame of a view can not be customized per-size class, you
>   need to make changes to your header view's frame while editing the
>   [wAny hAny] size class.

I was in the [wCompact hRegular] mode, which apparently you cannot set frame sizes in.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this question, try this:

```
UIView *v = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
CGRect fr = v.frame;
fr.size.height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -100;
v.frame = fr;
[self.tableView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

[Can't set constraints of UItableView's tableHeaderView height by autolayout in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330165/cant-set-constraints-of-uitableviews-tableheaderview-height-by-autolayout-in-s)

Answer (score 1):

For me in order to make it work, I needed to create an IBOutlet reference to the header view. Then I added in the viewDidLoad:

```
self.header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 40);
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a seperate NibFile and resize the nib file as per your required size (Resize the height manually do not use attribute inspector.).

Change Simulated metrics to freeform in attribute inspector.

Then You can customize the HeaderView .

```
 static NSString *SectionHeaderViewIdentifier = @"SectionHeaderViewIdentifier";
 #define HEADER_HEIGHT 200




    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];

            self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = HEADER_HEIGHT;

        // Set up default values.
        self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = HEADER_HEIGHT;

        UINib *sectionHeaderNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SectionHeaderView" bundle:nil];
        [self.tableView registerNib:sectionHeaderNib forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

    }

    -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        UIView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

        //You can customize your header view

        return sectionHeaderView;
    }
```

Comment: Why would I need to do this? I have other `UITableViewController's` in my storyboard that work correctly with a set hight tableView header.